# Periodic Strings

Tags: java, string

I am trying to solve this [String manipulation](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/external/4/455.html) problem, where I need to find the smallest period of a given string.

---

A string is said to have period k if it can be formed by concatenating one or more     repetitions of another string of length k.

---

For example, the string "abcabcabcabc" has period 3, since it is formed by 4 repetitions of the string "abc". It also has periods 6 (two repetitions of "abcabc") and 12 (one repetition of "abcabcabcabc"). Here's my code :

---

```
public static int getPeriod(String str){
    int len=str.length();   
    boolean flag=false;
    int i;
    
    for (i=0;i<len;i++){
        String s=str.substring(0,i);
        String tmp=str;

        while(tmp.length()>0){
            if(tmp.startsWith(s)){
                tmp=tmp.substring(0,i);
                flag=true;
            }
            
            else {
                flag=false;
                continue;
            }
        }
        
        if (flag==true)
            break;
    }
    
    return i;
 }
```

---

I am forming a string `s` by looping through the original string, one character at a time. After, that I am checking if the original string can be completely exhausted by concatenating the string `s` any number of times, or not.

---

ERROR:

> The method always returns 0.
>
> Why is that so ?

---

**EDIT : My algorithm**

Lets consider the input string `HoHoHo`

```
First step: s=H
        tmp= HoHoHo
        tmp= oHoHo (after substringing tmp)
        'o' isn't the same as s, so we increase i



   Second step:s=Ho
            tmp= HoHoHo
            tmp= HoHo (after substringing tmp)
            tmp= Ho (after substringing tmp)
            tmp= "" (after substringing tmp)
       
Return the value of i, that is 2.
```

Comment: I think there is some problem with your logic of programm

Comment: Please throw some light on that !!

Comment: I have placed one program which I have solved just now , you may check that.

Comment: I can't understand the logic of your algorithm. Put some comments in there to describe what the algorithm is supposed to do. One obvious thing to fix is to start at 1 rather than 0. Another thing to do is to use meaningful variable names rather than tmp and flag, and to avoid using break and continue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code inside the while loop isn't correct, it's called during the first invocation of the for loop with `i=0` and hence the first assignment to the `tmp` variable sets it to the empty string, the loop exits and you get 0. The flag assignments and the `continue` in the `else` are not correct too.
Try this:

```
public static int getPeriod(String str) {
    int len = str.length();
    int i;

    for (i = 1; i <= len/2; i++) {
        String period = str.substring(0, i);
        String tmp = str;
        boolean flag = true;

        while (flag && tmp.length() > 0) {
            if (tmp.startsWith(period)) {
                tmp = tmp.substring(i);
            } else {
                flag = false;
            }
        }

        if (flag == true) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Notice that the `for` loop starts from `1` and goes to `len/2` because you don't want to check for the zero length period and there can't be periods longer than `n/2`.

Answer (score 2):

In the first loop iteration, i == 0, so s is "" (empty string), and tmp is also "" after the first iteration over `while` loop, so `tmp` also becomes "" and exits all the loops.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with i = 0 will always return true because substring(0,0) will return the "" string and tmp.startsWith("") is always true.

First you should start i from 1, also you should replace `continue` with `break`, because `continue` will continue your `while loop` but what you want to do is `continue` the `for loop` and not the while loop

Here is a version of your code working:

```
public static int getPeriod(String str){
    int len=str.length();   
    boolean flag=false;
    int i;

    for (i=1;i<len;i++){
        String s=str.substring(0,i);
        String tmp=str;

        while(tmp.length()>0){
            if(tmp.startsWith(s)){
                tmp=tmp.substring(i);
                flag=true;
            }

            else {
                flag=false;
                break; 
                // Replaced continue with break to exit the while loop and pass 
                // to the next value in the for loop
            }
        }

        if (flag==true)
            break;
    }

    return i;
 }
```

Comment: Yeah.. that may be a possible bug. But how can I get through without initializing i=0

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question. The problem can be solved in linear time using Knuth's Prefix Function.

```
  public static int prefixFunction(final String needle)
    {
        //This code does not include input validation. Validate the input and return appropriate error message

        int[] pf = new int[needle.length()];
        for (int i = 1; i < needle.length(); i++)
        {
            int j = pf[i - 1];
            while (j > 0 && needle.charAt(i) != needle.charAt(j)) j--;
            if (needle.charAt(i) == needle.charAt(j)) ++j;
            pf[i] = j;
        }
        int n = needle.length(), maxValue = pf[n - 1];
        if(maxValue == 0 || n%(n-maxValue) != 0) return -1; //Not periodic 
        return needle.length() - maxValue;
    }
```